# Retrieve information from WSDL file using xmllint in Bash

Tags: xml, bash, scripting, wsdl

Can I use `xmllint` to retrieve information from a ".wsdl" file similar to how I would from an ".xml" file in Bash?

To put things into context, I have an xml file, which I use `xmllint` to get certain information in the following way in my Bash script:

```
init_variable=$(xmllint --xpath 'string(/tag1/tag2/tag3/attribute)' SampleMessages.xml)
```

where the "tags" represent the hierarchy in my xml and the attribute is the content of the attribute I retrieve the information from. This code works when the file is ".xml"

When I try to do the same with a ".wsdl" file, I get an error. Essentially, I'm trying to do the same thing as above with `xmllint`. However, each tag in that file is preceded with an `wsdl:` (see example below).

I'm trying to run the following:

```
serviceDescription=$(xmllint --xpath 'string(/wsdl:tag1/wsdl:tag2/wsdl:attribute)' ExampleFile.wsdl)
```

When I run the bash script, I get the following error in my terminal:

> XPath error : Undefined namespace prefix
>
> xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed
>
> XPath evaluation failure

I'm not sure what the error means, nor do I know if I can run `xmllint` on a ".wsdl" file as I have with an ".xml"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution and it is to use [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)

More information can also be found in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56826)